# Dark Souls - change xbox sticks to always run instead of walk to running?

Tags: steam, pc, controllers, dark-souls

When you slightly move the stick your character walks, when you move the stick all the way your character runs. Is there a way so that it always runs? My controller is dodgy in that moving the stick north-west or south-east all the way my character walks. I think changing the sticks from gradual to always running (like how WASD works without controller) would fix this issue, but I have no idea how to change it.

Comment: It's probably outside the scope of what you want to do, but you can download a controller driver emulator, like but not specifically motioninjoy, and use your controller as a remapped keyboard. since keyboard keys don't typically have sensitivity measures, it will allow you to map buttons to the stick... otherwise you'd have to find a way to disable sensitivity on the stick and/or set it to a certain threshold beyond the "walk" angle